# Como puedo evitar el doble submit de un formulario en laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola tengo este formulario que se envia por un modal...

```
<form action="{{url('/canjear_producto')}}" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkSubmit();">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <div class="modal-body">
              ¿ Estas seguro de que quieres canjear {{$c->name}}?
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$c->id}}" name="id_producto">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$c->price}}" name="price_producto">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$puntos_acumulados_disponibles[0]->r}}" name="puntos_acumulados">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$c->condicion}}" name="condicion">
              </div>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">NO</button>
            <button id="btsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SI</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Cuando al boton con id btsubmit se envia 2 veces la peticion... Como puedo prevenir eso?.. osea que cuando le de doble click rapidamente no se envie 2 veces... probe con varios script que no me funcionaron... alguna ayuda?

```
function checkSubmit() {
  document.getElementById("btsubmit").value = "Enviando...";
  document.getElementById("btsubmit").disabled = true;
  return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer previniendo el evento del submit, de esta manera `e.preventDefault();`

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btsubmit');

btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){

e.preventDefault();

})
```

```html
<form action="mipagina.html">
<button type="submit" id="btsubmit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: no me funciona... no se si es porque el formulario esta en un modal o porque.. estoy muy frustrado

Comment: Si te re-direcciona a la página de tu `action`?

Answer (score 0):

¿Puede ser un problema con tu función `checkSubmit()`?

La llamas en el form así:

```
onsubmit="return checkSubmit();"
```

prueba a quitar ese *return*. Con jQuery podemos tener efectos inesperados.

Si capturas el evento de envío de formulario con Vainilla JS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="mx-auto w-50">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <div class="modal-body">
                ¿ Estas seguro de que quieres canjear xxx?
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$c->id}}" name="id_producto">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$c->price}}" name="price_producto">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$puntos_acumulados_disponibles[0]->r}}" name="puntos_acumulados">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$c->condicion}}" name="condicion">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">NO</button>
                <button id="btsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SI</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        const form = document.querySelector('form')
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            console.log('formulario enviado');

            // Tu código...

            // form.submit();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Con jQuery:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="mx-auto w-50">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <div class="modal-body">
                ¿ Estas seguro de que quieres canjear xxx?
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$c->id}}" name="id_producto">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$c->price}}" name="price_producto">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$puntos_acumulados_disponibles[0]->r}}" name="puntos_acumulados">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$c->condicion}}" name="condicion">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">NO</button>
                <button id="btsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SI</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            const form = $('form');
            form.submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                console.log('formulario enviado');

                // Tu código...

                // form.submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como veras en comentado el `form.submit()` en ambos ejemplos.
Eres libre de descomentarlo.
Para el caso, como no hay contenido en el *action*, con *Vainilla JS* el formulario se envía y se recarga la página, es rápido y lo único que ocurre es que no ves el `console.log`.
Con jQuery, sin embargo, entras en un bucle de envio y recarga infinito...